# Cannot build correct SELECT in MySql

Tags: mysql, select, if-not-exists, top

Please help me to create a correct MySql query, which I failed to do.

I have 2 tables in our DB:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_audit` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `audit_event` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `data` varchar(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `source_ip` varchar(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_agent` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `create_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=27181 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_balance_transactions` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `audit_event_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `private_tournament_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `regular_tournament_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `points` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `create_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `private_tournament_id` (`private_tournament_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1001 ;
```

I have 2 audit events that I'm interested in:

```
user_audit.audit_event = "RGL_TOURNAMENT_ENTRANCE_PAID"
user_audit.audit_event = "RGL_TOURNAMENT_ENTRANCE_REFUNDED"
```

These audit events are opposite to each other, meaning user can pay, then can be refunded, then use pays again and so on.

On top of these 2 table I have to build one SQL select statement that will return `DISTINCT user_id, regular_tournament_id, create_timestamp` of ALL USERS with:

1. `user_balance_transactions.regular_tournament_id` is not `NULL`
2. `user_balance_transactions.audit_event_id` is pointing to `user_audit` table where `user_audit.audit_event = 'RGL_TOURNAMENT_ENTRANCE_PAID'` 
   and it's the **last event** (most important!) that happened chronologically.

   **IMPORTANT**: In `user_audit` table 2 possible audit events are related to each other: `'RGL_TOURNAMENT_ENTRANCE_PAID'` and `'RGL_TOURNAMENT_ENTRANCE_REFUNDED'`, 
   but we need `user_id` only of such users who has  `'RGL_TOURNAMENT_ENTRANCE_PAID'` event as last.
3. `create_timestamp` is a timestamp of this last event -  `'RGL_TOURNAMENT_ENTRANCE_PAID'`

---

A. Test data for "user_balance_transactions" table:

```
id, user_ID, audit_event_id, private_tournament_id, regular_tournament_id, points, description, create_timestamp

2, 23, 1711, null, 77, 10, "credit", "2015-06-12T17:23:44"

3, 23, 1712, null, 77, -10, "debit", "2015-06-12T17:41:44"

4, 23, 1713, null, 77, 10, "credit", "2015-06-12T18:11:44"
```

B. Test data for "user_audit" table:

```
id, user_ID, audit_event, data, source_ip, user_agent, create_timestamp

1711, 23, "RGL_TOURNAMENT_ENTRANCE_PAID", "","","", "2015-06-12T17:23:44"

1712, 23, "RGL_TOURNAMENT_ENTRANCE_REFUNDED", "","","", "2015-06-12T17:41:44"

1713, 23, "RGL_TOURNAMENT_ENTRANCE_PAID", "","","", "2015-06-12T18:11:44"
```

C. Expected SQL output:

```
user_id, regular_tournament_id, create_timestamp

23, 77, "2015-06-12T18:11:44" (last RGL_TOURNAMENT_ENTRANCE_PAID event)
```

---

"user_balance_transactions" stores user transaction and "user_audit" stores all user audit events, of which some of them related to the balance transactions.

That's why "user_balance_transactions" table has a Foreign Key to "user_audit" table "audit_event_id"

Comment: Can you add your expected output and some test values? Help us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
       t.user_id, 
       t.audit_event 
FROM
        (SELECT ua.user_id, ua.audit_event FROM user_audit ua, user_balance_transactions ubt WHERE
        (audit_event = 'RGL_TOURNAMENT_ENTRANCE_PAID' OR audit_event = 'RGL_TOURNAMENT_ENTRANCE_REFUNDED')
        AND ubt.regular_tournament_id='{$tournament_id}'
        AND ubt.audit_event_id=ua.id
        ORDER BY ua.create_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) t
        WHERE t.audit_event != 'RGL_TOURNAMENT_ENTRANCE_REFUNDED'
```

Comment: I tried and it does not work. Always returns just one user instead the list of distinctive users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MAX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-column.html) function to get the max value from `create_time` of `user_balance_transactions` table.

```
SELECT
    ua.user_id,
    ubt.regular_tournament_id,
    MAX(ubt.create_timestamp) as event_date,
    ua.audit_event
FROM test.user_audit AS ua
LEFT JOIN test.user_balance_transactions AS ubt ON (ubt.audit_event_id=ua.id AND ubt.user_id=ua.user_id AND ua.audit_event='RGL_TOURNAMENT_ENTRANCE_PAID')
GROUP BY ua.user_id;
```

### UPDATE:

Test:

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     ua.user_id,
    ->     ubt.regular_tournament_id,
    ->     MAX(ubt.create_timestamp) as event_date,
    ->     ua.audit_event
    -> FROM test.user_audit AS ua
    -> LEFT JOIN test.user_balance_transactions AS ubt ON (ubt.audit_event_id=ua.id AND ubt.user_id=ua.user_id AND ua.audit_event='RGL_TOURNAMENT_ENTRANCE_PAID')
    -> GROUP BY ua.user_id;
+---------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| user_id | regular_tournament_id | event_date          | audit_event                  |
+---------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
|      23 |                    77 | 2015-06-12 18:11:44 | RGL_TOURNAMENT_ENTRANCE_PAID |
+---------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't work

Comment: It's working as you see on the update, but, what's not working for you?